# NSOperation does not spawn a new thread?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, locking, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have a NSOperationQueue with a number of NSOperations in it. I want to ensure that a particular part of the code is not executed in parallel. I use a NSLock object like this:

```
[myLock lock]
some critical code
[myLock unlock]
```

Unfortunately instead of a blocking "lock" call I get the following error:

-[NSLock lock]: deadlock ( '(null)')

After some investigation I noticed that all NSOperations seem to run in the same thread. I drew that conclusion after logging the thread id with:

```
NSLog(@"Thread %@\n", self, [NSThread currentThread]);
```

**All** operations seem to run in the same thread. Even though they are running in parallel as operations.

Does that make sense? I am a little confused. Do I miss something? Do you see any problem with using NSOperation and NSLock together? (If not, then I am sure the error is in my code)

Comment: Can you post more code? More context? Also, is this on Mac OS X or iOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it. I am using ASIHTTPRequest underneath. Apparently all HTTP calls are made in the same thread unless you override "+ (NSThread *)threadForRequest:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request".

Sorry.

Comment: mhh. How can I indicate that this question is answered now? I cannot delete the question nor accept my own answer. :-(